# Customizing jQuery Mobile checkboxes labels

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've a `<fieldset>` of checkboxes with custom labels that contains both item names and descriptions, as you can see here:

[image: Custom checkboxes]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zw823/

On the third checkbox I need to have a custom `<input type="number" />` below description, which will be editable only if its checkbox is checked. Is it possible? I tried to put a `<div data-role="fieldcontain">` with label+input below the `<p>`, but the `<input/>` number didn't display as expected... How can I achieve that goal? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to do what you want. The trick is to load the jquery scripts at the bottom of the page, so you don't have to call `trigger('create')` and break your code.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" >
 <label for="check-1" >
  <a class="ui-li-heading" href="">Service 1</a>
  <p class="ui-li-desc">Lorem ipsum text</p>
 </label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" data-iconpos="left">
</fieldset>
<!-- rest of your data-role="page" -->
</div> <!-- end of page -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont know exactly why i have to load the scripts at the end of my page but it did the trick! awesome. thanks

Comment: You're welcome, can you mark the answer as the correct one? thanks a lot